# C++ MFC Write file to inserted USB Drive

Tags: c++, mfc, usb, hid, read-write

I'm using this [code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal) to determine when a usb drive is attached to the computer (I want to look for a certain one, if that one is inserted then the program does something).

The part that I'm stuck on is how to write to that drive.  If I use CFile to specify the file location, how do I know what drive letter windows assigned to that usb drive?  That's where my question is.  How do I write to that usb drive.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message for a USB disk then `lParam` will contain a pointer to the [`DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363249.aspx) structure. Having verified that its `dbcv_devicetype` is `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME` you can then look at its `dbcv_unitmask` member which shows which drive letter(s) the disk has.

Comment: Thank you.  The method I'm using and the DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME require Windows XP or greater, I know this wasn't part of my original question, but do you know of a method that would work for older versions of Windows (maybe back to 2000)?  Thanks again,

Comment: @mgalal dbcv_unitmask exists in VC6, so I think it should work in Windows 95; is that early enough for you?

Comment: @mgalal Indeed, it's really annoying that Microsoft remove all mention of older versions from their documentation.

Comment: Tell me about it...at least it was even documented